# Overwrite width only in CSS with an {if} rule

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on adjusting a slider right now, when going from 2-3 images it changes class. Now i want 4 images, and it works alright, however the slider bullets (that changes between the slider images) isn't in center of the page anymore, it's aligned slightly right.

Here's the script i use in HTML for changing from 2-3 images.

```html
 <{if $category->getMetaValue('slider_link_two') || $category->getMetaValue('slider_link_three')}>
    <ul class="glide__bullets">
    </ul>
<{/if}>
```

Here's the CSS, i apologize for layout, only have the minified css.

```css
.glide__bullets {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 18px;
 width: 97%;
 text-align: center;
 list-style: none;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none
}
.glide__bullets li {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: gray;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 margin: 0 5px;
 cursor: pointer
}
.glide__bullets li.active {
 background-color: white
}
```

As you can see I made a temporary solution of changing the width to 97%, but once you switch back to 3 images it will look stupid. I tried making a class to overwrite the width to 97% when there's 4 categories, but it completely ruins the bullets, but maybe it's just because i suck at coding.

So how can i change the width to 97% only when there's 4 images, or even better - keep it aligned center once there's 4 images. I tried running another  rule with three and four, but as mentioned above it seemed to completely ruin the layout.

If you need anymore let me know, thanks in advance!

Comment: A tag is missing here, this is not HTML syntax..

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and to me it seems fine unless i am not understanding what you are trying to achieve these are the results i got [3 bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxQ7G.png) and [4 bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6GW5.png) could you please explain better what it is you are trying to achieve. Thanks :)

Comment: this should go in comments

Comment: i know i just dont have enough reputation to put in a comment :( new to stackoverflow so trying to get my rep up sorry bout that

Comment: I might not have been clear enough, sorry about that. This is running on my page, the problem isn't getting 4 bullets, that works. The problem is once i got 4 bullets it's not aligned center anymore, it's aligned slightly to the right.